# Example of includes in GroovyDoc Gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle project with Groovy and Java source files.
For one of the packages "com.myorg....dsl" I'd like to generate the documentation using the `GroovyDoc`.
The following is by groovy doc configuration in the gradle file

```
groovydoc {
    groovyClasspath = project.configurations.jansi
    includes  = { "**/dsl/**" }
}
```

The intend of [includes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Groovydoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Groovydoc:includes) property is to only generate the documentation for packages with name *dsl*. But I'm not using the syntax right as the gradle script is failing.

Any example on the correct usage of `includes` is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the script failing? With what error?

Comment: @Opal The following exception is raised  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.iterator(Unknown Source)
 at org.gradle.api.tasks.util.PatternSet.include(PatternSet.java:199)
 at org.gradle.api.tasks.util.PatternSet.setIncludes(PatternSet.java:190)`

Comment: It should be `includes = ["**/dsl/**"]` or `include "**/dsl/**"`.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly well. Thanks @Opal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's invalid syntax in the code sample you provided. Should be either:

```
groovydoc {
    groovyClasspath = project.configurations.jansi
    includes  = ["**/dsl/**"]
}
```

or:

```
groovydoc {
    groovyClasspath = project.configurations.jansi
    include "**/dsl/**" 
}
```